# What command can I use to find out the version of docker swarm I am using?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode

I am unable to find a command that returns to me the docker swarm version I have installed. 
abcd@lenovo9fh04:simple$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Wed Jan 18 16:20:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Wed Jan 18 16:20:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
abcd@lenovo9fh04:simple$ docker swarm version

Usage:  docker swarm COMMAND

Manage Swarm

Options:
      --help   Print usage

Commands:
  init        Initialize a swarm
  join        Join a swarm as a node and/or manager
  join-token  Manage join tokens
  leave       Leave the swarm
  unlock      Unlock swarm
  unlock-key  Manage the unlock key
  update      Update the swarm

Run 'docker swarm COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.

Answer (score 2):

Swarm mode (not to be confused with the classic swarm that runs as a container or swarmkit that is used to develop swarm mode) is part of the docker engine and doesn't have a separate version number. You would simply refer to the 1.13 engine when specifying the release of swarm mode that you're using.